# Git Flow merging a release branch back to Development

Tags: git, git-flow

I have a feature branch (let's call it A) that I've merged with my Development branch from which I've created a release-A branch which has no changes. I merged release-A to master and have tagged master with a release identifier. Git Flow says that release-A should be merged back to Development but I'm reasonably assuming this is only needed if there are differences between release A and Development?

I'm supposing that if a branch from Development is taken and then merged back, then Git will realise that there are no differences and effectively ignore the merge?

I'm pretty new to Git so please excuse if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since release-A and Development branches point both to the same commit, merging will not change anything. So yes, `git` realizes that there is nothing to do.

**EDIT** for "simple" questions like this, you can always create a dummy git repository and see what happens. In this case:

```
mkdir test
cd test
git init
echo a > a
git add a
git commit -m "add a"
git branch release-A
git merge release-A
```

this gives:

> Already up to date.

Comment: This is true when you just copy the whole Development branch into a new release branch. But what if you have some other commits in the Development branch, that you don't want to be moved to the new release?
In that case, wouldn't you need to do a cherry-pick into the release branch?
If you **then** want to do a merge-back of the release into the Development, you would get a merge-commit, and in the end two same commits, since they have a different hash. How to avoid this?